# Want to transclude a MediaWiki page and preserve magic vars like {{PAGENAME}}

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to transclude a page, but preserve magic, page-specific variables like {{PAGENAME}}?

Let's say I have two pages:

**TranscludedPage** which contains {{PAGENAME}} and **ParentPage** which transcludes the former page with {{:TranscludedPage}}. As it turns out, {{PAGENAME}} will show ParentPage. What want it to do is to display TranscludedPage. Or, put differently, I want render the page as it would be rendered as an independent page, and then include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that directly in current MediaWiki (at least: which I know of). Basically, the `{{PAGENAME}}`’s *raison d’être* is exactly the opposite. If you need *static* content (not changing upon inclusion), save the TranscludedPage with `{{subst:PAGENAME}}`, and you’ll get static content.

(I guess there are various tricks on various levels (API, Speical:ExpandTemplates, custom extension) which could do something similar, but that would depend on what you really need to achieve.)

Comment: Close, but no cigar. Neither subst: nor ExpandTemplates are dynamic, which is what I wished for. However, I've found a different way of doing what I wanted to achieve, that doesn't require the dynamic re-rendering I asked for.